# Rounding and sorting dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

https://github.com/haosmark/jupyter_notebooks/blob/master/Coursera%20week%203%20assignment.ipynb
All the way at the bottom of the code, with question 3, I'm trying to average, round, and sort the data, however for some reason rounding and sorting isn't working at all

```
i = df.columns.get_loc('2006')
avgGDP = df[df.columns[i:]].copy()
avgGDP = avgGDP.mean(axis=1).round(2).sort_values(ascending=False)
avgGDP
```

what am I doing wrong here?

This is what df looks like before I apply average, round, and sort.
[image]

Comment: What is your df? Did you do exactly the same all the other questions until this point? I think it's better if you show us your exact code to maybe see what might have gone wrong

Comment: github link has everything, the code, and the outputs, on a cell-by-cell basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your series is actually sorted, the first line being `1.5e+13` and the last one `4.4e+11`:

```
Country
United States         1.536434e+13
China                 6.348609e+12
Japan                 5.542208e+12
Germany               3.493025e+12
France                2.681725e+12
United Kingdom        2.487907e+12
Brazil                2.189794e+12
Italy                 2.120175e+12
India                 1.769297e+12
Canada                1.660648e+12
Russian Federation    1.565460e+12
Spain                 1.418078e+12
Australia             1.164043e+12
South Korea           1.106714e+12
Iran                  4.441558e+11
```

Rounding doesn't do anything visible here because the smallest value is `4e+11`, and rounding it to 2 decimal places doesn't show on this scale. If you want to keep only 2 decimal places in the scientific notation, you can use `.map('{:0.2e}'.format)`, see my note below.

**Note:** just for fun, you could also calculate the same with a one-liner:

```
df.filter(regex='^2').mean(1).sort_values()[::-1].map('{:0.2e}'.format)
```

Output:

```
Country
United States         1.54e+13
China                 6.35e+12
Japan                 5.54e+12
Germany               3.49e+12
France                2.68e+12
United Kingdom        2.49e+12
Brazil                2.19e+12
Italy                 2.12e+12
India                 1.77e+12
Canada                1.66e+12
Russian Federation    1.57e+12
Spain                 1.42e+12
Australia             1.16e+12
South Korea           1.11e+12
Iran                  4.44e+11
```